# How to select "Don't save" with keyboard in this dialog?

Tags: macos, keyboard, shortcut, dialog

Whenever I close a file with unsaved changes, Sublime Text displays this dialog:

[image]

(Note that Save is selected by default)

In Windows, I would press "N" for "no" to close without saving changes, but in macOS it doesn't look like there's such a shortcut. I've also tried with the arrow keys and tab but the active button doesn't change.

How is this normally done in macOS?

Comment: **⌘D** works for me in Sublime Text 2. **⌘⌫** (Command-Delete) also works. Running macOD High Sierra.